# File Explorer Crash When Copy/Move Files Windows 11

Tags: windows-explorer, cmd.exe, copy-paste

First of all, I already knew the issue, and already "googling" & did multiple possible solutions to fix File Explorer Crash When Copy/Move Files. But unfortunately, the issue still not resolved yet.

I already tried:

1. DISM.exe
2. sfc /scannow
3. File explorer troubleshooting
4. Clean boot
5. Filex explorer restarting service
6. Registry & non microsoft service checking
   **7. Running script (run as administrator CMD) -> cmd /c "echo off | clip"**

[image: No. 7 Solution]

The **no. 7** solution fixed it, but only when the computer running. Every time when I turn the computer off then put it on again, the problem comes again, then I must running the script again.

So, basically I come for 2 questions:

1. Are there any solutions that I've missed?
2. If **no. 7** is the solution, how to make it automatically running when computer start up dan always run as administrator under C:\WINDOWS\system32> ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No issues here. It could be a context error causing problems.  I had that with Windows 10, and I had to a Repair Install keeping just Data.

Comment: @John actually I avoid to re-install the Windows because my company prohibit me to do that. Yes, I already told to my company's technician, but still no solutions

Comment: `cmd /c "echo off | clip"` simply clears the clipboard. I can't see any reason how that could solve the described issue. At startup, the clipboard should be empty by default. So if anything in the clipboard causes this issue, the big questions are: what/who put it into the clipboard? And what? And when? Check your autostarts.

Comment: @Stephan I've disabled autostarts, then check if some affect the problems. but it didn't spot the real problem though. clear the clipboard is my temporary solution by now

Answer (score 0):

Not that I advise using a work-around, rather than [reinstalling Windows 11 from ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=kXQk6*ivFEQ&ranSiteID=kXQk6.ivFEQ-NH3PI00AodaCCh7KlBHGUg&epi=kXQk6.ivFEQ-NH3PI00AodaCCh7KlBHGUg&irgwc=1&irclickid=_z0keysh3wskf6nkp133xftfux32xrcvu0svqhe0l00), but you can easily automate that script:

- Create a .bat file with `cmd /c "echo off | clip"` as its contents.
- On the Desktop, create a desktop shortcut to the batch file.
- Right-click the shortcut and select *Properties*.
- On the *Advanced* tab, set *Run as administrator* to true (checked).
- Move the shortcut to a *Startup* folder, either *System* or to the user's.

Comment: ... or simply create it as a scheduled task at login.

Comment: I already tried this and @Stephan's solution as well, and it didn't work for me